# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insertans()

Tags: php, laravel

I have encountered a laravel problem for insertin data in mysql database.

Here is my controller in web.php :

```
Route::post('/insertans', 'Controller@insertans');
```

This is my php function code for mysql :

```
function insertans(Request $req) {
        $question1 = $req->input('question1');
        $question2 = $req->input('question2');
        $question3 = $req->input('question3');

        $ans = array("question1"=>$question1,"question2"=>$question2,"question3"=>$question3);

        DB::table('jawaban')->insertans($ans);

        echo "Data successfully added";
    }
```

And this is my html for visual purpose

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PACKET A</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/insertans" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
                <td>1. &emsp; What does HTTP stands for?  </td>
                &emsp;<td><input type="text" name="question1"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>2. &emsp; What does JS stands for?  </td>
                &emsp;<td><input type="text" name="question2"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>3. &emsp; What does CSS stands for?  </td>
                &emsp;<td><input type="text" name="question3"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                <td><input type="reset" name="cls" value="Cancel"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please provide as much detail on the problem as is available.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `insertans()` method on the `Query Builder`, thats why you get the error.

You probably mean to do `DB::table('jawaban')->insert($ans);` instead of `DB::table('jawaban')->insertans($ans);`

Answer (score 1):

Use `insert()`:

```
DB::table('jawaban')->insert($ans);
```

`insertans()` is a controller method, you shouldn't use it when building the query.